# I am having trouble importing JSON data into access - Text Files

Tags: json, ms-access

I have a large amount of user logs in a JSON format in a excel sheet. The JSON is valid but it is in a text format. I have taken a small set and formatted them and placed them into individual files with Notepad++. My final goal is to take the JSON data and then analyze it but I am not sure if there are tools to achieve this. Most other information on the internet is importing JSON from web pages or from a database and this does not solve my problem. Any help would be amazing.

My main issue is that all of the data is in Excel or in individual JSON files and I am not able to access the database where it is kept. I cannot query data without placing it in a database of some kind for analysis.

```
   "tacurrency": "ROW",
   "cadloginvalid": true,
   "InitalCart": [
      {
         "cartitems3": {
         "ReturnPage": "",
         "Availability": "In Stock",
         "subtotal": 643,
         "description": "",
         "PartNo": "IFTK",
         "Custom": false,
         "unitprice": 643,
         "ArrayName": "Session.CartItems3",
         "extprice": 643,
         "Checked": false,
         "EmailNeeded": false,
         "Quantity": 1,
         "FromSaved": false
```

Not sure if this is helpful, here is a small sample with information taken out.

Comment: Have you researched how to read data from text files or excel files? It's a pretty common task. If you're in an Access environment then you could write VBA code to do it. Once you've got the data, if it's JSON then you can decode it

Comment: I haven't looked into that, I will now though. This is the kind of lead I am looking for, thank you.

Comment: Ok. To be honest it wasn't really so much a lead as a "have you Googled it yet?" question. Maybe the thing you forgot was to break the research down into the separate steps involved (read from data file, then process data) - your description of the job seemed to imply it was all a single process

Comment: I have googled things, just the wrong things it seems. I think you are right, I just was slightly overwhelmed attempting to solve a problem that is not really something I have encountered before. I appreciate the help.